# Hosting and setting up own shiny apps without shiny server

Tags: r, web-hosting, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to make shiny apps available to my coworkers without them having to run or even have R installed.

So I read [this webpage](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson7/)
and found this sentence:

> If you are familiar with web hosting or have access to an IT
>   department, you can host your Shiny apps yourself.

under the '*Share as a web page*'-section.

How can I do this?

The problem is that my company is bound to certain restrictions regarding web hosting and security and so on, and will not (for now) pay for a shiny-server-pro.

But the sentence above gives me hope to set up something ourselves to convince them.

Comment: Perhaps [getting started with shiny server](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server)?

Answer (score 106):

If your PC and your coworkers PCs belong to the same LAN, this is pretty easy to achieve. Just run your app through:

```
runApp(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 5050)
```

The value set through the `host` argument says to accept any connection (not just from localhost). The `port` argument can assume any value that you want (just assure to avoid to select ports used by other services like `ssh` or `http`). Then, take note of your local IP (if you are under linux, you can see it through `ifconfig`). Say your IP is `192.168.1.70`. Your colleagues can use your app by inserting in the address bar of their browser `192.168.1.70:5050`, i.e. your IP followed by `:` and the port number you selected.

If you want access from outside your LAN, you can direct your router to your PC when someone connect to your public IP through the 5050 port.

Comment: Thank you. Im gonna try it on Monday. But this means I have to have R and the app running while others access it?

Comment: Yes. Your application must be running on your pc.

Comment: Okay. I now tried it and it worked. But is there a possibility without running the app on my machine? like I said, we have access to an IT department and some servers and the quoted sentence indicates the possibility to do it.

Comment: The app must run somewhere. The machine that hosts it must have R, shiny and all the needed dependencies to make it run.

Comment: This is a very helpful post - my follow up question is, how many people can access the app at the same time?

Comment: Hi @nicola, would you please give me more information about how to "direct your router to your PC when someone connect to your public IP through the 5050 port"? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I'm a little late to the party on this one @nicola but I'm in a similar situation with needing to securely share a dashboard for free and your solution seems perfect. However, I have used my IP address and selected a port but it can't be opened by other computers in my office even though we're all connected to the same network. Does this need to be a static IP address that has a port dedicated to this dashboard?

Comment: Double check that you are using you are sharing your IP address with the given port to the other users (run `ipconfig` from the cmd). After this, I would try to use other ports. If that does not work contact your IT department, sometimes they restrict these ports and it is impossible to share any information using your IP.

Comment: Using `runApp(host="0.0.0.0", port=80)` you can also run your scrpt as a service. For Linux you will find several guides on how to install custom services  and using Windows you can configure RScript.exe as target and add your script as an argument via: http://nssm.cc/

Comment: hi, i've used this method and it works up until I try to import a csv file. The screen greys out on the second computer, but when i look at the console for the host computer there is no error and it's still running.

Comment: Is this better, worse, or equal to running the app using Open Source Shiny Server in a Docker container?

Comment: using runApp(host="0.0.0.0",port=5050) and sharing the public ip i think that is possible to open a only single app i'm wrong???

Comment: @KmnsE2 you can use multiple apps but you need to run then on different ports and different rsessions

Answer (score 40):

Sharing apps over the LAN like this is pretty cool, but it is kind of a hack. I tried it with some co-workers, and it works, but it is more of an office trick than a sustainable solution.

I just finished developing the [RInno](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno) package for this exact problem, i.e. when a company will not pay for Shiny Server or there are security concerns with cloud services.

To get started:

```
install.packages("RInno")
require(RInno)
RInno::install_inno()
```

Then you just need to call two functions to create an installation framework:

```
create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "path/to/myapp")
compile_iss()
```

If you would like to include R for your co-workers who don't have it installed, add `include_R = TRUE` to `create_app`:

```
create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "path/to/myapp", include_R = TRUE)
```

It defaults to include shiny, magrittr and jsonlite, so if you are using other packages like ggplot2 or plotly, just add them to the `pkgs` argument. You can also include GitHub packages to the `remotes` argument:

```
create_app(
    app_name = "myapp", 
    app_dir  = "path/to/myapp"
    pkgs     = c("shiny", "jsonlite", "magrittr", "plotly", "ggplot2"),
    remotes  = c("talgalili/installr", "daattali/shinyjs"))
```

If you are interested in other features, check out [FI Labs - RInno](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno)

Comment: Only for Windows ^^

Comment: Yep, I bought a Linux laptop and am looking at ways to support Ubuntu next

Answer (score 13):

You might want to have a look at the open source solution [shinyproxy](https://www.shinyproxy.io/).

Using shinyproxy you will have to wrap your apps in a docker container to host them.

[Here](https://www.shinyproxy.io/documentation/deploying-apps/) you can find a guide on how to deploy a shiny app in a docker container (which btw. is a good practice, even without using shinyproxy, to maintain the app dependencies).

There are different [authentication and scaling methods](https://www.shinyproxy.io/documentation/configuration/) available.

[Here](https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy) the according GitHub repository can be found.

Answer (score 5):

I have recently installed Shiny on a Centos 7 Linux OS server we have locally. We used the guide below for the most part.
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-shiny-server-on-centos-7

Feel free to ask any questions about setup problems here so anyone else using the guide can see the answers!

We also looked into pushing it up on a AWS server, opted for our own as the content is sensitive. Otherwise both solutions looked similar. The Linux and Shiny system are light, you might be able to run it on the free Amazon server!

Answer (score 2):

The Web [Hosting Data Apps](https://hosting.analythium.io/about/) has some tutorials to host Shiny apps using just [systemd](https://hosting.analythium.io/using-systemd-to-run-shiny-apps/) or [docker](https://hosting.analythium.io/host-shiny-apps-with-docker/) and make them globally accesible, you can check them out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another really "hacky" solution. I recently had to deal with the same issue you faced, and wasn't sure how to get some sort of POC in front of the eyes of those who make the decisions. I knew that they could access a particular shared network drive. So I saved the R binaries to that network drive. The app that I wrote was saved on that same network drive. I then wrote a .R file and saved it in the app's working directory that had these lines in it to set the working directory and source the global variables.

contents of app_start.R

```
setwd("shared/drive/app_directory")
source("./global.R")
runApp("launch.browser=TRUE")
```

All of this was started by a batch file (if windows, otherwise a .sh file) with one line that had two parts, the absolute filepath to the R binaries on the network drive, and then the .R script above to run the application

```
# something to the effect of 
filepath/to/R/bin/Rscript.exe filePath/to/app_start.R
```

It did the trick for a POC, but definitely would not be a production-worthy solution.