# Hosting and sharing shiny apps using public wifi?

Tags: shiny, web-hosting

I learned how to share my shiny app within intranet/same LAN, [hosting and setting up own shiny apps without shiny server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799722/hosting-and-setting-up-own-shiny-apps-without-shiny-server). Using `runApp(host="0.0.0.0",port=5050)`.

However I failed when I tried to do this between my laptop and phone while both connecting to a public wifi, GoogleStucks.

As a layman in web hosting stuff, my guess is GoogleStucks is actually not an intranet?

Answer (score 0):

I just finished developing the [RInno](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno) package which will allow you to share your app on Windows machines. If your question is more about sharing your Shiny apps than about GoogleStucks, then you should probably check it out ;)

To get started:

```
install.packages("RInno")
require(RInno)
RInno::install_inno()
```

Then you just need to call two functions to create an installation framework:

```
create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "path/to/myapp")
compile_iss()
```

If you would like to include R for your co-workers who don't have it installed, add `include_R = TRUE` to `create_app`:

```
create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "path/to/myapp", include_R = TRUE)
```

It defaults to include shiny, magrittr and jsonlite, so if you are using other packages like ggplot2 or plotly, just add them to the `pkgs` argument. You can also include GitHub packages to the `remotes` argument:

```
create_app(
    app_name = "myapp", 
    app_dir  = "path/to/myapp"
    pkgs     = c("shiny", "jsonlite", "magrittr", "plotly", "ggplot2"),
    remotes  = c("talgalili/installr", "daattali/shinyjs"))
```

If you are interested in other features, check out [FI Labs - RInno](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno)