# Is there a way to deploy R shiny apps as web page using windows server?

Tags: shiny, rstudio, shiny-server, shinydashboard, rstudio-server

Let me know if there is a way to deploy shiny dashboards as a webpage using windows server.

I know it is possible using Linux but it need it for windows.

Comment: Use some sort of `VM` such as virtual box to host shinyapps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hosting and setting up own shiny apps without shiny server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799722/hosting-and-setting-up-own-shiny-apps-without-shiny-server)

Comment: Alex, my question was on hosting with windows server. but the one you mentioned is on without server. you may want to recheck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put below code as last lines:

```
app <- shinyApp(ui,server)
runApp(app,host="0.0.0.0",port=5050)
```

Then to run you Shiny App in any other machine just give the IP of the machine where the code is deployed and the port number which is 5050 in this case.
So, for example if you code is deployed on a machine with IP: 123.12.123.12 then for any other machine just write 123.12.123.12:5050 on any web browser.

The only caveat is the machine where the code is deployed and the machine where you need to use these codes should be in same domain.

Comment: yes. this is for intranet. here  the user machine also needs to have the R installed. But we can't expect every user to have the same. suggest me if any other option is available.

Comment: No, the user machine can/can't have R. The R in the user machine is not a mandate.

Comment: I am 100% confident it works without the user machine having R. Caveat is same domain and the server machine or the machine where the code is deployed should be running all the time. If the code stops there, it will stop in all user machines