# How to avoid permission denied on shiny server for other users

Tags: r, shiny, debian, shiny-server

My colleagues have Setup a shiny Server on debian.

If i create an app and run it, i can see it at : `http://ourIP:8787/p/098a4074/`.

**Goal:**

Now, i want to make it visible for my colleagues.

**Error:**

If my colleagues open http://ourIP:8787/p/098a4074/ they will have to Login and get a permission denied. I cant publish the app outside of our Network.

**What i tried:**

I tried to give Rights on the Folders where the app files are stored via `chmod`. But i guess thats not where the app is published.

I tried to find Folders like: p/098a4074.

I feel like i am missing something fundamental and this is quite of a stupid Question. I would be very happy anyway if i could get some pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hosting and setting up own shiny apps without shiny server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799722/hosting-and-setting-up-own-shiny-apps-without-shiny-server)

Comment: Yes that works. Should have remembered that. Thank you.

Comment: If you have an internally facing server that is secured from the outside world, you can install a free shiny server, it is open-sourced, and serve it from there. And your admin can set it up to only allow certain IP's in, or require a VPN to access the server. We do this on an Azure cloud, but it could work on a Local network too...as server is a server.