# Shiny app on web domain and Windows server

Tags: r, shiny

I have developed a shiny app that runs on Windows. The idea is that many users can view the app when visiting a web domain. The data are updated daily by a Windows cron that executes a file in Powershell and then run the app. The app is executed independent of the data and reads the updated data from a folder. The app is static, it consists of multiple tabs that only show graphs and tables with updated data.

I would like to run the app on a Windows web server once a day, after updating the data, and have the app running all the time. I would appreciate if someone could tell me what would be the best way to put this app into production.

Comment: To run the app, you'll need [Shiny Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/), which isn't available directly for Windows. One solution is to run a Shiny Docker container, see [Rocker](https://www.rocker-project.org/images/)

Comment: Shiny server is not required to host a shiny app. There are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799722/hosting-and-setting-up-own-shiny-apps-without-shiny-server). However, I'd recommend using nginx or apache for Windows as a reverse proxy.