# Run shinyApp locally

Tags: r, url, shiny, local

I want to create a shinyApp that runs just locally, i.e. withouth a URL that can be accessed by others.

Here a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage("Some app")
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

While running this, the console says:

[image: console]

If I type the URL into my browser, I see the App I am writing on. How can I hinder the app to go online? This is important for my use case because we handle sensible data which must remain locally.

Comment: ? This is local port ? So you are not online?!

Comment: @TarJae How do I know this or to put it the other way around: What does "Listening on http://..." mean if not online?

Comment: So I see you have to go through some basic (no offense), I had to do it also and still I am not that clear about all this server side, local etc... So my tip is to start with <https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html>, but more important is that you understand how you can make your app public accessable. Then you will understand what is local and what is public. Think of a local network in your company where all of your members have access to your app, but no one outside the company etc.....

Comment: Please see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopbackand) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks (yo, vieles ist egal ;-) )

Comment: Just ignore the downvotes. Mission is to learn! Never give up!!! Have fun! :-)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26800937/9841389) you can find a related answer. Furthermore, the first link in my above comment is broken and I can't edit any longer - correct link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback

Comment: @ismirsehregal Great! First link dead, but could find it with the word that appears (Loopback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to leave a clear answer regarding your question:

**Your app never was online.**

Via 127.0.0.1 your browser is accessing the standard address for IPv4 loopback traffic on your localhost (your PC) - please see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

`runApp()`'s [default for the host parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73121648/9841389) is:

```
host = getOption("shiny.host", "127.0.0.1")
```

On the other hand using `runApp("0.0.0.0")` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799722/hosting-and-setting-up-own-shiny-apps-without-shiny-server/26800937#26800937) makes your app accessible from the LAN.

To share your shiny applications online you can e.g. publish them on [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/).